# Zeep with namespace(?) variables

Tags: python, zeep

I have an XML/WCF API I need to implement something against.  The API client library is only provided as c# in Windows and our company does not do either c# or Windows. I am now experimenting with Python and zeep. The api is Symmetry access control system API if anyone is interested.

I can connect to the server and read the wsdl structure. This works:

```
    URL='https://localhost/smsXMLWebService/SMSXMLWebService.svc?singleWsdl'
    URL2='https://localhost/smsXMLWebService/smsXMLWebService.svc'
    session = Session()
    session.verify = False
    transport = Transport(session=session)
    self.client = zeep.Client(URL, transport=transport)
    self.service = self.client.create_service('{http://tempuri.org/}WSHttpBinding_ISMSXMLWebService', URL2)
```

Now everything from that point forward will require login to the platform. In the example c# code this is done as follows:

```
G4TAPI = new SMSXMLWebServiceClient();
G4TAPI.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = txtUserName.Text
G4TAPI.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = txtPassword.Text.ToLower();
G4TAPI.G4TLogin();
```

My `self.service` has now G4TLogin() call and it seems to attempt to connect when I wireshark the traffic. But how do I set the username and password as they are not given as parameters to G4TLogin() method?

This does not work:

```
self.service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "api"
```

This is very much out of my comfort zone and I may be using incorrect terminology here. Any ideas?

The error message is

```
AttributeError: Service has no operation 'ClientCredentials'
```

Answer (score -1):

When using Zeep make sure to study the namespaces in WSDL URL, using

```
python -mzeep "YourWsdlUrlGoesHere"
```

Get the parameters and make a Python dictionary from them (in my case facing C#, including username and password in the dictionary) note that one might need to make nested dictionary like in my case.

```
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth,  HTTPDigestAuth

from zeep import Client

from zeep.transports import Transport



request =   { "Credential":{"Username": "yourusername",
  "Password": "yourpassword"},

  "RN": "150147119"
                        }

session = Session()

client = Client('http://your url and wsdl../Invoice.svc?Wsdl',transport=Transport(session=session))

r = client.service.NameOfYourService(request)

print(r)
```

Do not pass user and password in Zeep formal format. Passing the dictionary worked for me.
In my case the WSDL suggested user and password be in credential and a string be passed in RN and finally all be passed in a one variable.